# Error in y - ymean : non-numeric argument to binary operator randomForest R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, random-forest

I have a matrix which is about 37k x 1024 consisting of 1s and 0s as categorical variables to indicate the existence or absence of a feature vector. I ran this matrix through the randomForest package in R as follows :

```
rfr <- randomForest(X_train,Y_train)
```

Where X_train is the matrix containing the categorical variables and Y__train is a vector consisting of labels for every row in the matrix. When i run this, i get the following error :

```
Error in y - ymean : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I checked for any null values or missing data but didnt find any.

I even made the whole thing into a data.frame and tried the following

```
rfr <- randomForest(labels ~ ., data = featureDF)
```

Still had the same errors.

I would appreciate any help with this, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I'd guess that `labels` is a character variable, but `randomForest` expects categorical outcome variables to be factors. Change it to a factor and see if the error goes away:

```
featureDF$labels = factor(featureDF$labels)
```

The help for `randomForest` isn't explicit about the response needing to be a factor, but it's implied:

> ```
> y  A response vector. If a factor, classification is assumed, otherwise   
>    regression is assumed. If omitted, randomForest will run in unsupervised mode.
> ```

You haven't provided sample data, so here's an example with the built-in `iris` data:

`Species` is a factor in the original data frame. Let's convert `Species` to character:

```
iris$Species = as.character(iris$Species)
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
```

> ```
> Error in y - ymean : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> ```

After converting `Species` back to factor, `randomForest` runs without error.

```
iris$Species = factor(iris$Species)
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
```